# How to use caffeine getAll()?

Tags: java, caffeine-cache

The title is very straightforward, I am trying to use caffeine cache for my Minecraft plugin and I can't seem to find any good examples for `cache.getAll()`. The [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Cache.html#getAll) doesn't help either. All I see is `<`,`>`, and `?`. I really think that documentation should provide examples. So all I'm asking is if someone could provide an example

Comment: When you build the caffeine cache, you are building a type of `Cache<K,V>` where K is the key type, and V is the value type. Any operation that accepts `? extends K` is telling that method accepts a type/subtype of K.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually using the documentation you should be able to understand what it's expecting as arguments. The author did a very good job. If you don't, I'd suggest you to read on Java generics and understand the syntax.

#### TL;DR:

```java
Cache<String, Integer> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();

cache.getAll(List.of("one", "two", "three"), keys -> {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    keys.forEach(key -> {
        if (key.equals("one")) result.put(key, 1);
        else if (key.equals("two")) result.put(key, 2);
        else if (key.equals("three")) result.put(key, 3);
    });
    return result;
});
```

The example might not make much sense in terms of functionality, but it's an example.

#### The long version

The documentation has a method signature of:

> Map<K,​V> getAll​(Iterable<? extends K> keys, Function<? super Set<? extends K>,​? extends Map<? extends K,​? extends V>> mappingFunction)

Let's break this down.

> Map<K,​V> getAll​

The `getAll` method returns a Map with a key of type `K` and a value of type `V`. If your cache implementation is something like:

```java
Cache<String, Integer> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();
```

then `K == String` and `V == Integer`

The first argument of that method is:

> Iterable<? extends K> keys

Now `Iterable` is a JDK interface, which is implemented by pretty much all of the Collections. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true) for "known" implementing classes.
The question mark actually means "any type that extends `K`" (where `K` is String in the example)

So as a first argument we can use something like:

```java
List.of("one", "two")
```

> Function<? super Set<? extends K>,​? extends Map<? extends K,​? extends V>>

That might look confusing but it isn't if you try to break it down again. Function is an interface (that declares only one method, hence functional) that declares as the first type, the type of the input and as the second type, the type of the return. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html?is-external=true).

So `? super Set<? extends K>` is any type that is a superset of `Set` with elements of type `K` (aka String in the example). Why the author opted for the `super` keyword? Google what *"PECS"* is (producer extends, consumer super).

And then `​? extends Map<? extends K,​? extends V>` is as you have figured out, an implementation of `Map` with keys of type `K` and values of type `V` (or Integer).

#### Notes

> Returns a map of the values associated with the keys, creating or retrieving those values if necessary. The returned map contains entries that were already cached, combined with the newly loaded entries; it will never contain null keys or values.

Self explanatory but note that the returned map would have all cache values and your `mappingFunction`'s results combined - without `null` keys/values

> A single request to the mappingFunction is performed for all keys which are not already present in the cache

Your `mappingFunction` will be called only once, with a list of all the keys that were requested but not found in the cache.

> All entries returned by `mappingFunction` will be stored in the cache, over-writing any previously cached values

Self explanatory as well, the map that the `mappingFunction` returns will replace or be stored in cache

Answer (score 1):

The [user-guide](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population) provides a simple examples of this functionality. A `getAll` method is available in all flavors of the cache.

##### Synchronous cache

In this abstraction, the caller will block waiting for the loads to complete

```java
Cache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();
cache.put(k1, v1);

// Loads k2 & k3 (uses k1)
Map<Key, Graph> graphs = cache.getAll(Set.of(k1, k2, k3),
    keys -> createExpensiveGraphs(keys));
```

If you wish to decouple the caller from the loading function, then create a `LoadingCache`. If the supplied `CacheLoader` does not implement bulk functionality, then it will fallback to one-by-one loading.

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .build(CacheLoader.bulk(keys -> createExpensiveGraphs(keys)));
Map<Key, Graph> graphs = cache.getAll(keys);
```

Note that in this abstraction loads are non-blocking. If a `getAll` is retrieving `k2` and a blocking `get(k2)` occurs concurrently then both loads will be in-flight. When the `getAll` completes it will overwrite the existing value. This behavior is because we cannot lock multiple entries in `ConcurrentHashMap` compute methods, but that concern is resolved if using an `AsyncCache`.

##### Asynchronous Cache

In this abstraction the cache stores a mapping to a `CompletableFuture` and returns that to the caller. You can either call with a synchronous function that wraps as asynchronous, or use an asynchronous function that returns the futures directly.

```java
AsyncCache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync();
CompletableFuture<Map<Key, Graph>> graphs1 = cache.getAll(Set.of(k1, k2, k3),
    keys -> createExpensiveGraphs(keys));
CompletableFuture<Map<Key, Graph>> graphs2 = cache.getAll(Set.of(k1, k2, k3),
    (keys, executor) -> createExpensiveGraphFutures(keys));
```

The loading logic can be hidden from the caller using an `AsyncLoadingCache`.

```java
AsyncLoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .build(AsyncCacheLoader.bulk(keys -> createExpensiveGraphs(keys)));
CompletableFuture<Map<Key, Graph>> graphs = cache.getAll(keys);
```

In this abstraction `getAll` will block subsequent `get` calls for the same key. This is due to the underlying map holding an in-flight future entry, so placeholders are inserted and completed when the bulk operation is done.